# Ascending order arrangement of numbers of a file

Tags: c

How to read a file which contains two columns and sort the first column numbers in ascending order and to print them with their corresponnding 2nd column values using C ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.   Your question will be better received if you follow the guidelines, which are presented to you in the "How To Ask" section on the right when you ask a question.   http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: To get you started, first work on reading the line from a file (see `scanf`, `fgets` or `getline`) and storing them in a data structure (an array of pointers to char will work). Then work on parsing the first column into something that can be sorted (an array perhaps). Then sort based on your first column applying the results to your array of pointers. Work on it, get your code together along with sample data and update your question. That will provide a basis for help.

Comment: use sort comannd or use awk or perl.

Answer (score 0):

`fopen` opens a file.

`fscanf` reads from a file and splits what is read into bits according to a format specification (e.g. `"%d %s"` means an integer followed by whitespace followed by a string of non-whitespace characters).

`qsort` is a standard library function that will sort an array.  It sorts the array by comparing one item to another item.  You give it the name of a function (which you write) that does this comparison.

I encourage you to read the manual pages for these functions if you are not familiar with them.

The program below uses all this to:

1. Open a file `test.txt`
2. Read lines from the file into an array `arr`
3. Sort the array using `qsort`, using the rowcmp function (rowcmp looks at the numerical value in the first column to determine whether one element is greater than, equal to, or less than another element)
4. Print out the elements of the array.

The code...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXLEN 100
#define MAXITEMS 100

// A row has two columns, the first is a number and
// the second is any string of up to MAXLEN chars
struct row {
    int col1;
    char col2[MAXLEN];
};

// Function to do comparison of rows
// Sorts numerically on the value in the first column
int rowcmp(struct row * r1, struct row * r2) {
    if (r1->col1 < r2->col1) return -1;
    if (r1->col1 == r2->col1) return 0; 
    return 1; 
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

    struct row arr[MAXITEMS]; // up to MAXITEMS rows
    int rows = 0, i;
    FILE * stream = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    // Read in rows and put first and second columns into struct,
    // building up an array
    while (fscanf(stream, "%d %s", &(arr[rows].col1), arr[rows].col2) !=EOF) {
        rows++;
    }

    // Sort the array using the rowcmp function to compare items
    qsort(&arr[0], rows, sizeof(struct row), (__compar_fn_t)rowcmp);

    fclose(stream);

    // Print the sorted array
    for (i=0; i<rows; i++) {
        printf("%d\t%s\n", arr[i].col1, arr[i].col2);
    }
}
```

With input file:

```
1 apple
3 cucumbers
21 dates
7 figs
4 grapes
```

output is

```
1   apple
3   cucumbers
4   grapes
7   figs
21  dates
```